# Setting up Windows Server 2012 with a NAS

Tags: backup, network-shares, nas, windows-server-2012-r2

Looking to set up a Synology DS412+ NAS on a Windows 2012 Server for backups and extra storage. How do you make the NAS viewable on the network? I have been trying for 3 days with no luck.
I can FTP to the NAS and I did set up a iSCSI and gave admin rights on the NAS. I can do a FTP back up from the server but I can't see the NAS as a network item like my other computers or drives.

Also tried mapping no good..

Comment: Did you have a "Shared Folder" (Control Panel - Shared Folder), and make sure it is not set to hidden. And also did you enable SMB (Control Panel - Win/Mac/NFS - Enable Windows File Service)?

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple shared folders on the nas, the problem is in server 2012, it if I try to connect to the disk station by ip I can connect to it and see the \\backupfolders but it wont show up as a network backup server as per little icon saying disk station or little icon with the ip under it...

Comment: Sorry I'm not too clear what your issue is.. you said you can connect to the NAS using IP address.. so problem are you having? What feature are you trying to use on Windows Server 2012 that somehow unable to see the NAS folder? (That you already can access) Can you clarify. Closest thing I can guess based on what you said is "Windows Server Backup" feature.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying the problem, i'm trying to get the nas to show up on the network, clicking on start, and then going to my computer and seeing all the network locations/computers and network drives it just doesn't show up, if i type the ip addy i can see the backup folder \\Server Backup\volume01 but when i try and map the nas as a network storage or drive it wont do it just tells me its not on the network or it can't find it,i tried using the synology software new ver 4.3 on the server to find the nas but no luck also turned off the fire wall still no luck.

Comment: I don't think this is the NAS issue as I have Synology with same DSM version (4.3). You may just need to turn on "Network Discovery" on your Windows Server. It is under Control Panel - All Control Panel Items - Network and sharing Center - Advanced Sharing Settings. You need to enable Network Discovery for the correct network profile. So if you set that your LAN is on "Private" then turn on Network Discovery on that profile. See if that helps.

Comment: I agree the first thing i checked was for discovery it is correct,i don't thinks its a problem with the nas either,i think its just a setting in the server config file being either adding a module for shares or giving rights but its setup on the admin side so  i made a shortcut to the start menu with the ip and i can click it and the backup files show up and i can drop a file from the server to the nas's ip by drag and drop and log into the nas from another computer on the network and the file is there but it's just driving we crazy why the computer icon wont show up under network locations

Comment: Is the service "Computer Browser" running? (located under services.msc), also, Synology has their own firewall, see if you can temporarily kill it and if it works after that. Also do you have any other machine running other OS to do testing?

Comment: i will recheck tonight but i would think so being i can see all the other computers on the network, and yes i run a windows 8.1pro rig also, and it shows up on the server in the network location,

Answer (score -1):

Synology uses smb2 but Win Server 2012 only uses smb3.  At this point, the only option is to use iscsi initiator on the server and setup an iscsi LUN on the NAS.

Comment: I have many Windows 2003,2008 and 2012 server using CIFS shares to many synology of various models on my network. on my network.

I would use NFS for windows before I would use iSCSI for a Share on windows.  iSCSI is going to limit him to a single user, because iSCSI is a block device.